# Check the document index of sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I've done some complex regexp_filters in Sphinx which work well for some purposes but break the 'normal' search for the word in question. Is there a way to see what Sphinx has actually indexed those words to internally so I can then call them that way when needed as 'stand-alone word? Some command I can give to read the actual indexed document(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get it from the index. The index isnt actully in a format suitable to extract per document text.

But do look at the `indextool` command, in particular `--dumpdict`, and maybe `--dumphitlist`. Also the `--fold` option might be useful (I dont know for sure if it runs the regexp_filtrs)